# You must cut a wire of $36cm$ to form a triangle and a rectangle in a specific place to find the minimum area.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Well, I have an wire of $36cm$ and I need to cut it in two parts, one to form an equilateral triangle, and the other to form a rectangle such that its width is two times the height. Where do I need to cut this wire such that the área is minimum?

If we let $x$ be the part used for the rectangle, then $36-x$ is left for the triangle, where wach side will be $\frac{36-x}{3}$. The formula for the area of a equilateral triangle is:
$$\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}(36-x)^2$$
Then if $x$ is for the rectangle, we should have $4$ parts, but two of them are double the others. How Shuld I express the width and height in terms of $x$?

Then the problem is basically about summing the two áreas and finding the point where the derivative is $0$, right?

Comment: If the perimeter of the rectangle is $x$, the height is $x/6$ and the width is $(2x)/6=x/3$.  You find that by saying $w=2h, 2w+2h=x, 6h=x, h=x/6$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula for the area of your triangle looks wrong.

Area of triangle given sides $a, b$ and angle $\theta$ between them $= \frac{1}{2}ab\sin\theta$.

In this case that's $\displaystyle (\frac{1}{2})(\frac{36-x}{3})^2(\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}) = \frac{\sqrt 3}{36}(36-x)^2$

And since for the rectangle, width is twice height($h$), the total perimeter is $2(2h+h) = 6h = x$. Hence $h = \frac{x}{6}$, and the area is $2h^2 = \frac{x^2}{18}$.

Add those two expressions and minimise.

Comment: ops, I forgot to write $(36-x)/3$

Comment: Wolfram alpha gives  http://bit.ly/12UWFb4 which is approx 16.7 which is the answer I got, but my book gives 19.3cm, which one is right?

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs I haven't verified the values myself but both look like they could be right, depending on how each is indicating the position of the cut. Don't they sum to 36cm? The important thing is that you make clear if the length you're referring to is the rectangular or the triangular portion.